# Xslt transforms, changing part of the text of a connection string only

Tags: c#, xslt, connection-string

I've been swapping out connectionstrings wholesale wtih xlst for a while thusly

```
<xsl:template match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='SybaseDB']/@connectionString" >
   <xsl:attribute name="connectionString">
      <xsl:text>host='LeroyJenkins.org';Pooling=true;Port='5100';UID='LeroyJenkins';Password='12345';Database='LeroyJenkins';Min Pool Size=5;Load Balance Timeout=30;Max Pool Size=50;Connection Timeout=60000;Workstation ID='LeroyJenkins';Fetch Buffer Size=4096;Clone Connection If Needed=True</xsl:text>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

But what if I want to modify just the

```
;Password='12345'
```

element to replace `12345` with a different value? Say "LeroyJenkins"...

How can I do this?

I found lots of posts on doing substring manipulation in xslt.. but I'm afraid I wasn't able to figure out how to apply this to my situation.

I'm using this tool : TransformXml.exe from this article..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16549/TransformXML-a-command-line-utility-to-apply-XSL-t

If someone could explain what's going on so I can internalize & apply it, I'd greatly appreciate that.

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: This is normally not a good thing or recommended thing to do but you can checkout this site and read it carefully it has an example towards the bottom of what I think you are looking for..  if those values were stored in a app.config file for example it would be even easier to alter.. but check this out... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/DynamicXSL09262006000549AM/DynamicXSL.aspx

Comment: It's in an app.config, Our CM seems incapable of putting the right passwords in the config on promotion to qa/prod, so I'm trying to make a quick and dirty tool to do it using xslt (so I can add or remove changes via an external xslt transform file)

Comment: Gotta hate that .. Incompetent CM's I feel your pain on a daily basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat more elaborate than just string manipulation. It transforms the connection string into an XML structure, replaces the password, and puts it back together. You should be able to replace other items, than just the password, by modifying the `change-password` template at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="target-name">SybaseDB</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="new-password">NEWPASSWORD</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name=$target-name">
                <xsl:variable name="items">
                    <xsl:call-template name="parse-connetion-string">
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@connectionString"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:variable name="items-new-password">
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="change-password" select="exsl:node-set($items)"/>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="connectionString">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="generate-connection-string" select="exsl:node-set($items-new-password)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="parse-connetion-string">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>

        <xsl:variable name="itemString">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($text,';')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,';')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="itemName" select="substring-before($itemString,'=')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="itemValue" select="substring-after($itemString,'=')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rest" select="substring-after($text,';')"/>

        <item name="{$itemName}" value="{$itemValue}"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($rest)!=0">
            <xsl:call-template name="parse-connetion-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$rest"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="generate-connection-string">
        <xsl:if test="position() != 1">;</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" mode="change-password">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name='Password'">
                <item name="{@name}" value="'{$new-password}'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that it does not recognize "exsl", I changed it from calling that EXE to do this instead :XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(); xslt.Load( transformFileName ); xslt.Transform(inputFileName, outputFileName); Is that what messed it up? I figured the newer version would work better. Thanks!

Comment: System.XMl.Xsl.XslLoadException: Prefix 'exsl' is not defined

Comment: Did you include the whole file? The namespace is defined in the xsl:stylesheet tag at the top. XsltCompiledTransform should also natively support the EXSLT extension functions exslt:node-set() and exsl:object-type(). See http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000714.html

Comment: That was it, I'd pasted it in to my existing xsls and left those two lins off the header. Thanks!

Comment: It works but when it regenerate the Connection string, it leaves out the name="SybaseDB" tag... Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Fixed. I added `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`.